# class not changing in data.frame after NA cleaning in R

Tags: r, dataframe, class, lapply

I have an `input` data.frame that contains two unwanted elements (i.e., `"#N/A",'p'`) in it. I clean and replace the elements with `NA`.

Then, I remove all rows with `NA` to get a fully clean data.frame with the first (`id`) and the last (`read_2018`) columns ONLY consisting of numerics.

**Question:** WHY STILL class of `id` and `read_2018` is factor? How to fix this automatically for any data.frame in a FUNCTIONAL manner (e.g., using a `loop`)?!

That is, after full cleaning, I want any column that consists of ALL numerics becomes of class numeric, anything that is ALL character becomes of class character etc.?

```
input <- data.frame(id = c(1,"#N/A",3, 4), school = LETTERS[1:4], read_2018 =c("#N/A",'p',9, 8))

sapply(input, class)  ## check class of all columns

 #>      id    school read_2018 
 #>  "factor"  "factor"  "factor"

  replace = c("#N/A", 'p')     # Unwanted elements to be replaced
  with = NA                    # with `NA`

 input[sapply(input, `%in%`, replace)] <- with ## Now replace unwanted elements with `NA`

 input <- na.omit(input)   ## Remove all rows with `NA`

 sapply(input, class)      ## class of clean `input` without `NA` or character elements

 #>     id      school  read_2018     ###@@@ WHY STILL class of id and read_2018 is factor? How to fix?!
 #>  "factor"  "factor"  "factor"
```

Comment: @akrun, someone suggested closing the question, to avoid downvote for you and me I deleted the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `map` to get the class

```
input <- type.convert(input, as.is = TRUE)
```

If we have a previous version of `R` i.e. R version < 3.5 or so, do

```
input[] <- lapply(input, function(x) type.convert(as.character(x), as.is = TRUE))
```

then with `map`, get the `class`

```
library(purrr)
map_chr(input, class)
```

---

Or in `base R` with `lapply` and `unlist`

```
unlist(lapply(input, class))
```

Comment: @rnorouzian let me check

Comment: @rnorouzian it is working fine for me `str(type.convert(input, as.is = TRUE))# 
'data.frame': 3837 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ stid     : int  300365 300365 300365 300437 300437 300437 300475 300530 300942 300942 ...
 $ scid     : chr  "Carmichael" "Carmichael" "Carmichael" "Johnson" ...
 $ group    : chr  "T" "T" "T" "C" ...
 $ gender   : chr  "Female" "Female" "Female" "Female" ...
 $ ethnicity: chr  "Afamerican" "Afamerican" "Afamerican" "Hispanic" ...
 $ LEP      : chr  "None" "None" "None" "LEP" ...`

Comment: @rnorouzian can you check the `R version`.  I have R 3.6.2

Comment: @rnorouzian if you have a previous R version, do `input[] <- lapply(input, function(x) type.convert(as.character(x), as.is = TRUE))` I think the `type.convert` for `data.frame` method was added only in the recent version (I hope I am not wrong)

Comment: @rnorouzian in that case, do the `lapply` way

Comment: @rnorouzian can you please test the updated code.  BTW, in the new R version, 4.0.0, the default is `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`

Comment: @rnorouzian the `type.convert` output is assigned to the same object and then when you check the `class`, it is the `class` of the corrected one from `type.convert`.  So, not clear why you need a second assignment.  The `lapply(input, class)` was done after the correct with `type.convert`

Comment: @rnorouzian the `type.convert` is a function to convert to different classes based on the values of that column so that we don't have to check and do this from our end

Answer (score 2):

Once you have removed any unwanted data, classes would not automatically change.

You can use `type.convert` which converts data to appropriate class.

```
input <- type.convert(input, as.is = TRUE)
sapply(input, class)

#        id      school   read_2018 
#  "integer" "character"   "integer"
```

Comment: What is `class(data)` ?

Comment: I guess the data has some columns with a different class. Change it to one common class. Use `data[] <- lapply(data, as.character)` and then try the above,